# Laravel eloquent: get data with model wherePivot equal to custom field

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have an eloquent object Performer that has Albums and Albums have Images

Here is setup:

**Model Performer->albums():**

```
public function albums()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Album','performer_albums','performer_id','album_id');
}
```

**Model Album->images()**

```
public function images()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Image','album_images','album_id','image_id')->withPivot(['type','size']);
}
```

I have performer object stored as such:

```
$performer = Performer::where...->first();
```

Now I need to get Performer's Albums with images where `size` is 'large'

So to avoid nesting queries, can I use with()?

I tried

```
$performer->albums()
          ->with('images')
          ->wherePivot('size','large')
          ->get();
```

But laravel tells me it's trying to use wherePivot for Performer-Album relationship (M-2-M)

---

PS. I am also aware that I can do this,

```
$performer = Performer::with('albums')
                      ->with('albums.images')
                      ->.....-conditions for additional fields in album_images....
                      ->get();
```

but question remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [eager load constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$performer->albums()
  ->with(['images' => function ($q) {
      $q->wherePivot('size','large');
  }])
  ->get();
```

And btw, no, you can't do this:

```
Performer::with('albums')
  ->with('albums.images')
  ->.....-conditions for additional fields in album_images....
  ->get();
```

instead you could do:

```
Performer::with(['albums.images' => function ($q) {
     $q->   .....-conditions for additional fields in album_images....
  }])->get();
```